# change exchange content in camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am trying to implement a scenario using camel which is as follows:-

1. Get File From JMS queue.
2. Store the file and crc value of the file in a directory
3. Move the file and crc file to the SFTP server and once it is successfull
   delete the files from the directory.

My route is as follows

```
from("jms:queue")
 .to(save the file)
 .process(since I have the content of the file in exchange so generating crc)
 .to(file system save the crc file)
 .to(Push both the files to the sftp server);
```

But the file that is getting uploaded to the sftp server is only crc file as it was present in the exchange.
How should I solve this Situation?
If anyone of you have come across to this problem Please Guide me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a [wire tap](http://camel.apache.org/wire-tap.html) to copy your exchange to a different route and have that new route save the file and sftp it to the correct location.

```
from("jms:queue")
  .wireTap("direct:save-file")
  .process(since I have the content of the file in exchange so generating crc)
  .to(file system save the crc file)
  .to(Push file to the sftp server);

from("direct:save-file")
  .to(save the file)
  .to(Push file to the sftp server);
```